# Uncaugt SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - app.js18

Tags: javascript

I'm currently beginner to Javascript and recently my assignment require to create a 2d Runner game
So I'm get stuck at the end of the code. when I thought I add correctly the parentheses and braces but  I still got error.

Here's the code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

// GLOBAL ELEMENTS //


const player = document.querySelector ('.player');
const body = document.querySelector ('.body');
const grid = document.querySelector ('grid');
const menu = document.getElementById ('menu');
const heading=document.getElementById ('heading');

// INPUT SETTING //
document.addEventListener ('keydown', (e)=> {
    if (e.code === "Space") {
       console.log ("Space bar pressed");
    }
    
document.addEventListener ('touchstart', (e)=> {
    console.log("TOUCHED");
});
```

Comment: If you just clicked on your file name in the console error you will find the error position to fix it - just not closed brackets, parentheses 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed your keydown event properly. Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=> {
  if (e.code === "Space") {
    console.log ("Space bar pressed");
  }
});
```

You also need another "});" to close the event listener.

Style note: It is preferable not to have a space between function name and parameter, e.g.:

```
console.log('hi');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but I still get the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input, I even delete my part and paste yours but It still caught error.

Comment: _"You have not closed your keydown event properly"_ - That would be a _"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo - While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."_ close-vote and not an answer

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer. I thought you just posted a snippet. My edit was that you need another "});" at the end.

Comment: @Andreas Syntax errors by beginners are typos? Ok.

Comment: Questions and answers on SO should help OP and future readers. How is a missing `})` in that specific setup helpful for future readers?

Comment: OP also misses the closing brackets for `.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'`. But yeah it is questionable if this question should even receive an answer.

Comment: So how do we help a person in a case like this? We just don't?

Comment: Explain the typo and vote to close as such. A down vote would also be okay because this type of error (basic function syntax) is solvable with a bit of research or a linter or an IDE or an online editor or... - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-Stack-Overflow-users)